# Revit API Try to Get all the elements from Revit File

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to get all the revit element from the revit file.I trying to get the all the element have the parameter "Edited by".How to get that because getting all element from.

```
FilteredElementCollector Fec = new FilteredElementCollector(revitDoc);

Parameter is giving null exception in some case.

 FilteredElementCollector Fec = new FilteredElementCollector(revitDoc);
 allElements.ForEach(element =>
            {
                Parameter parameter = <element.GetParameters("Edited by").FirstOrDefault();
              
                string parameterValve = null;
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    parameterValve = parameter.AsString();

                }
                elementModifiedInfo.Add(element, parameterValve);
            });
```

Parameter is geting null in some case.
How to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FilteredElementCollector` is definitely the right way to go. The [GetParameters method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/0cf342ef-c64f-b0b7-cbec-da8f3428a7dc.htm) returns a list. The list may be empty. You need to add a check for that situation as well.

Furthermore, you cannot retrieve all elements without adding any filter criteria. The `FilteredElementCollector` requires at least one filter. An obvious one in this case might be [`WhereElementIsNotElementType`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/061cbbb9-26f1-a8f8-a4b2-3d7ff0105199.htm), to eliminate all types from your filter. This is explained in the article [Do Not Filter For All Elements](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/filter-for-all-elements.html).

Finally, you can significantly enhance performance when searching for specific parameter values by using an [`ElementParameterFilter`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/b0b40351-690c-eb5d-30c2-d4447a42fda1.htm). Check out The Building Coder samples demonstrating how to use that:

- [Parameter Filter Units](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/12/parameter-filter-units.html)
- [Retrieving Newly Created Elements in Revit 2011](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/retrieving-newly-created-elements-in-revit-2011.html)
- [Parameter Filter](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/parameter-filter.html)
- [Element Name Parameter Filter Correction](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/element-name-parameter-filter-correction.html)
- [ElementParameterFilter with a Shared Parameter](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/08/elementparameterfilter-with-a-shared-parameter.html)
- [Filtered Element Collectors](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/filtered-element-collectors.html)
- [Melbourne Day One](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/melbourne-day-one.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2011 API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/02/whats-new-in-the-revit-2011-api.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2014 API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2014-api.html)
- [State of the View and Data API, vA3C and Edge Ids](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/03/state-of-the-view-and-data-api-va3c-and-edge-ids.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2019 API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2019-api.html)
- [Forge Tutorials and Filtering for a Parameter Value](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/06/forge-tutorials-and-filtering-for-a-parameter-value.html)
- [Forge Tutorials and Filtering for a Parameter Value](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/06/forge-tutorials-and-filtering-for-a-parameter-value.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2019.1 API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/08/whats-new-in-the-revit-20191-api.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2020 API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2020-api.html)
- [Parameter Filter Checking Element Type and OCR](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/01/parameter-filter-checking-element-type-and-ocr.html)
- [Parameter Filter Checking Element Type and OCR](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/01/parameter-filter-checking-element-type-and-ocr.html)
- [Utility Classes and Constraining Stirrups](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2022/02/utility-classes-and-constraining-stirrups.html)

To wrap up, you can learn all else you need to know about this topic from The Building Coder articles on [Retrieving Elements Using FilteredElementCollector](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.9).